# Selenium Unable to find element in IE with switch frame

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am creating in selenium a process that only runs in IE and I can not locate the xpath as a consequence.

I was able to advance the test using switch frame,

When switching to the frame "**frame1**" or try identify element (**id:txtChassi**) is where the error occurs:

***Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id frame1***

***Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #txtChassi***

**Try One:**

```
driver0.switchTo().frame("frame1");

WebElement IptBoxChassi = driver0.findElement(By.id("txtChassi"));
IptBoxChassi.sendKeys(rs.getString(cChassi));
```

**Try Two:**

```
WebDriverWait waitIptBoxChassi = new WebDriverWait(driver0, 10);                        

waitIptBoxChassi.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("txtChassi")));

 WebElement IptBoxChassi = driver0.findElement(By.id("txtChassi"));
    IptBoxChassi.sendKeys(rs.getString(cChassi));
```

**Here more data from Error and WebPage:**

[image]

```
<FRAME noResize marginHeight=0 src="tela_topo.asp" frameBorder=no name=top marginWidth=0 scrolling=no target="contents">
```

[image]

```
<FRAMESET id=frame1 border=0 cols="157,*,0'" onunload="javascript: if (!(fechando)) window.location.href = '/controleacesso/encerrar.asp';"><FRAME noResize marginHeight=0 src="pre_menu.asp" frameBorder=no name=contents marginWidth=0 scrolling=no target="form"><FRAMESET id=frameAbaixo border=0 rows=*%,17%,0% onunload="javascript: if (!(fechando)) window.location.href = '/controleacesso/encerrar.asp';"><FRAME noResize marginHeight=0 src="tela_direita.asp" frameBorder=no name=form marginWidth=0><FRAME noResize marginHeight=0 src="pre_botoes.asp" frameBorder=no name=botoes marginWidth=0 scrolling=no><FRAME noResize marginHeight=0 src="Home/Home.asp" frameBorder=no name=Consulta marginWidth=0></FRAMESET><FRAMESET id=framelado border=5 rows=*,17% onunload="javascript: if (!(fechando)) window.location.href = '/controleacesso/encerrar.asp';"><FRAME noResize marginHeight=0 src="tela_direita.asp" frameBorder=no name=formlado marginWidth=0><FRAME noResize marginHeight=0 src="pre_botoes.asp" frameBorder=no name=botoeslado marginWidth=0 scrolling=no></FRAMESET></FRAMESET>
```

[image]

```
<FRAME noResize marginHeight=0 src="pre_menu.asp" frameBorder=no name=contents marginWidth=0 scrolling=no target="form">
```

**Here is where error happens, WebDriver dont see the element in the frame**

[image]

```
<FORM id=form1 method=post name=form1 action=RegistroContrato.asp><INPUT id=oculto type=hidden name=oculto> <INPUT type=hidden name=idPessoa> <INPUT id=ocultoIdTransacao type=hidden name=ocultoIdTransacao> <INPUT id=ocultoIdAgenteFinanceiro type=hidden name=ocultoIdAgenteFinanceiro> <INPUT id=ocultoCNPJCredor type=hidden name=ocultoCNPJCredor> <INPUT id=ocultoNomeCredor type=hidden name=ocultoNomeCredor> <INPUT id=ocultoCPFCNPJDevedor type=hidden name=ocultoCPFCNPJDevedor> <INPUT id=ocultoNomeDevedor type=hidden name=ocultoNomeDevedor> <INPUT id=ocultoSequencia type=hidden name=ocultoSequencia> <INPUT id=ocultoPlaca type=hidden name=ocultoPlaca> <INPUT id=ocultoRenavam type=hidden name=ocultoRenavam> <INPUT id=ocultoUF type=hidden name=ocultoUF> <INPUT id=ocultoMarcaModelo type=hidden name=ocultoMarcaModelo> <INPUT id=ocultoAnoFabricacao type=hidden name=ocultoAnoFabricacao> <INPUT id=ocultoAnoModelo type=hidden name=ocultoAnoModelo> <INPUT id=ocultoEspecie type=hidden name=ocultoEspecie> <INPUT id=ocultoTipoVeiculo type=hidden name=ocultoTipoVeiculo> <INPUT id=ocultoCombustivel type=hidden name=ocultoCombustivel> <INPUT id=ocultoCategoria type=hidden name=ocultoCategoria> <INPUT id=ocultoDataContrato type=hidden name=ocultoDataContrato> <INPUT id=ocultoCodigoTipoContrato type=hidden name=ocultoCodigoTipoContrato> <INPUT id=ocultoDescricaoTipoContrato type=hidden name=ocultoDescricaoTipoContrato> <INPUT id=ocultoStatusContrato type=hidden name=ocultoStatusContrato> 
<TABLE cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=0 width="90%" align=center border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD width="15%">Chassi:&nbsp;</TD>
<TD width="85%"><INPUT onkeypress=javascript:ValidaCaracter(); id=txtChassi class=box maxLength=20 size=30 name=txtChassi> </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD width="15%">Contrato:&nbsp;</TD>
<TD width="85%"><INPUT id=txtNumeroContrato class=box maxLength=20 size=30 name=txtNumeroContrato> </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=2 noWrap>
<HR color=#376cb7 SIZE=1>
</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ERROR 1:**

1. make sure that your element is in iFrame then only you have to switch into required iframe and perform the actions on required element.
2. If you have switched into some iFrame earlier then don't forget to switch back from that iframe (once worked has been done) to work with some other element on normal webpage.

e.g.

- Switch by frame webelement

  ```
  WebElement frame = driver.FindElement(By.locator);
  driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
  ```
- Switch in using index

  ```
  driver.switchTo().frame(0); // frame index 0, 1 and so on
  ```
- Switch in using ExplicitWait (will wait until given frame available and once available then switch in)

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.locator));

  ....

  //perform action on webelement inside iframe

  ....

  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();  // switchback from frame

  /* if there is any other iframe and you have to work within then again you have to switch into other iframe as well as shown above*/
  ```

**ERROR 2:**

1. If your element is not within iframe (if element is in iframe then it shows NoSuchElementException) then use Implicit or Explicit code until the said element gets available to perform the action.

Minor Observation : It is saying *Unable to find element with css selector == #txtChassi* but you are using `By.id`

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.
I have not had success yet.
I can not even identify the frame.
Includes new information in the main thread.